# ¿Cómo obtener la historia de un paquete de CRAN?

Tags: r

Quisiera saber de que forma poder obtener la lista de versiones de un determinado paquete del repositorio de CRAN, hasta ahora lo que pude observar es que con cada paquete se van manteniendo las versiones subidas, por ejemplo tomando como caso `shiny`, podemos acceder a esta [`url`](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shiny/) donde podemos ver las versiones subidas, la fecha y eventualmente descargarnos dicha versión. Se me ocurrió procesar el HTML y obtener estos datos, pero hay ¿alguna otra forma más directa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma cómoda es usar la funcionalidad del paquete [`pkgcache`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgcache/index.html), puntualmente, para listar las versiones:

```
subset(pkgcache::cran_archive_list(), package == 'shiny')

# A data frame: 43 × 6
   package version raw                      mtime               url                                                 mirror              
 * <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                    <dttm>              <chr>                                               <chr>               
 1 shiny   0.2.3   shiny/shiny_0.2.3.tar.gz 2012-12-01 04:16:21 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 2 shiny   0.2.4   shiny/shiny_0.2.4.tar.gz 2012-12-18 11:52:11 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 3 shiny   0.3.0   shiny/shiny_0.3.0.tar.gz 2013-01-24 04:08:45 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 4 shiny   0.4.0   shiny/shiny_0.4.0.tar.gz 2013-02-22 04:23:41 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 5 shiny   0.5.0   shiny/shiny_0.5.0.tar.gz 2013-03-29 04:58:49 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 6 shiny   0.6.0   shiny/shiny_0.6.0.tar.gz 2013-06-05 15:56:28 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 7 shiny   0.7.0   shiny/shiny_0.7.0.tar.gz 2013-08-27 12:21:08 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 8 shiny   0.8.0   shiny/shiny_0.8.0.tar.gz 2013-10-30 03:33:50 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
 9 shiny   0.9.0   shiny/shiny_0.9.0.tar.gz 2014-03-18 17:22:13 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
10 shiny   0.9.1   shiny/shiny_0.9.1.tar.gz 2014-03-19 16:56:55 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sh… https://cloud.r-pro…
# … with 33 more rows
```

La funcionalidad se basa en que CRAN publica una base de datos `Rds` con toda esta información, así que aún sin usar este paquete, no es muy complicado implementar un función que permita resolver este tema:

```
get_pkg_history_from_cran <- local({ 
  
  meta <- paste0(contrib.url(getOption("repos"), "source"), "/Meta/archive.rds")
  con <- gzcon(url(meta, "rb"))
  cran_history <- readRDS(con)
  rm(meta, con)
  
  function(pkgname) { 
    df <- cran_history[[pkgname]]
    df$pkgname <- pkgname
    df$file <- rownames(df)
    rownames(df) <- NULL
    df[ , c("pkgname", "file", "size", "mtime", "uname", "grname")]
    }
})

head(get_pkg_history_from_cran("shiny"))
  pkgname                        file    size               mtime  uname    grname
1   shiny   shiny/shiny_0.10.0.tar.gz  973769 2014-06-14 02:29:57 ripley cranadmin
2   shiny   shiny/shiny_0.10.1.tar.gz  978367 2014-07-26 04:02:37 ripley cranadmin
3   shiny shiny/shiny_0.10.2.1.tar.gz  995078 2014-10-01 13:40:47 hornik cranadmin
4   shiny shiny/shiny_0.10.2.2.tar.gz  995046 2014-12-08 17:48:32 ripley cranadmin
5   shiny   shiny/shiny_0.10.2.tar.gz  995265 2014-09-30 03:01:29 ripley cranadmin
6   shiny   shiny/shiny_0.11.1.tar.gz 1305406 2015-02-10 21:00:44 ligges cranadmin
```

Nota: La función está diseñada para "cachear" los metadatos entre cada ejecución.